# Align the rotation of game pieces to a central point?

Tags: game-engine

I have a lot of game pieces that all need to be aligned differently. If I could automatically align a piece's Z axis to matched it's relationship line, that would be perfect. The other option would be to align them to be perpendicular to the face of the object it rests on, (which is not the parent. The parent is an empty in the center of the game.)

Comment: @quasipseudo: I suggest you create a thread on blenderartists.org in the game engine work in progress section. It would be easier to answer your questions there as all of your questions are related.